# Admin password will not respond

Tags: 16.04

I have Ubuntu 16.04 LTS.  Computer was fine yesterday afternoon, but when I fired it up in the evening it kept asking me for my admin password.  What I typed in was correct - many times.  I just can't get into my computer! It's not a new computer. Please advise. I am using my employer's laptop to write this.

Hello my computer keyboard is English and very old (the letters are fading on it)  I'm sorry, I don;t know what encrypted means.  I am just a typist (not a very good one on this laptop!)

Arijit - I'm sorry, I clicked on "him" to thank you and say was doing what you suggested and it has taken me to a website.  Could you please re-send your instructions again.  They seemed easy to follow but your post has disappeared!

Hello again Arijit - I realised what I have done - no need to re-send!  This is a struggle for me.

Comment: is your keyboard layout an english one, because if not, it might be that your system accidently changed to an english one - had this problem once after installing

Comment: if you did not encrypt your system one of the answers in this post might help https://askubuntu.com/questions/24006/how-do-i-reset-a-lost-administrative-password

Answer (score -1):

@Melanie: 
1. Boot into recovery mode from the Grub menu (using `shift` key if Ubuntu is the only OS)
2. After the boot, go to the option `Drop to Root Shell Prompt`
3. Type `mount -o rw,remount /`
4. To reset Password, type `passwd username` (your username)
5. Then type a new Password and exit from the shell to the recovery menu
6. Select `resume normal boot`
7. Select Ok
8. Use your Ubuntu with the new Password

Regards

You may Thank [him](http://www.psychocats.net/ubuntu/resetpassword) for the solution.

Comment: We can't find Root Shell Prompt after the boot.

Comment: I am glad it helped. Regards

Comment: As I use a dual boot, in my case it's Advanced options for Ubuntu. Pressing Enter shows me a recovery mode.

Comment: Do you think we should choose 45 or 42?

Comment: I guess either of the two shall work.

Comment: Sorry we got into a mess at stage 4 - we are trying again.

Comment: No worries . If you succeed, just give me an up vote please .

Comment: Do I have to delete the password for the named account.  I am on a page with a lot of options.  Do I just put in a new password at the bottom of the page where the prompt is?

Comment: I think the new password will do, when you press Enter after the new password, you may have to repeat the password again

Comment: My new password - computer says command not found and is giving me a lot of similar alternatives

Comment: New password is not a command. The command is passwd melanie (if that's your username), press Enter. Then type the password you want to set.

Comment: Hello Arijit - we did everything, but the new password is not working. Thanks for all your help.  We will have to take the computer to the repair shop to see if they can do anything.  I'll give you a vote up (if I can work out how to do it)  Melanie

Comment: Wait, if you have a Ubuntu Live DVD with you, try this http://askubuntu.com/a/435347/519116